# Significance of squared in meters per second squared

Tags: unit-of-measure

What exactly is the difference between $3 \mathrm m/\mathrm s^2$ and $3 \mathrm m/\mathrm s$? According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meters_per_second_squared#Example)...

> An object experiences a constant acceleration of one metre per second squared (1 m/s²) from a state of rest, when it achieves the speed of 5 m/s after 5 seconds and 10 m/s after 10 seconds.

From this, it seems like that $1 \mathrm m/\mathrm s^2 = 1 \mathrm m/\mathrm s$, though that wouldn't make sense considering how they're treated as separate units.

Comment: It's better to think of it as a (meter per second) per second, i.e. (m/s)/s.

Comment: This is a physics question, better ask it there. In short, $m/s$ is a unit of _velocity_ and $m/s^2$ is a unit of _acceleration_ (rate of change of the former). Those are two very different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a snapshot of a space rocket starting with its engines burning, exactly at the moment when it begins to move. Its velocity is still $0 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}}$, but its acceleration can be over $20 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^2}$.

Now, imagine a shuttle in space. It might have huge velocity, but without its engines burning (and disregarding the gravity of the Sun, the Earth, the Moon, etc.), its acceleration is zero.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0):

The first one is an acceleration, whereas the second one is a velocity.

For cars it would be "from 0 to 100mph in 3 seconds" (or, strictly speaking, the inverse of that) vs. maximum speed "200mph"...

Comment: Ohh, that already makes much more sense. I was almost interpreting it as a velocity where in a 10 second period, you'd have moved value * sqrt(10) meters or something, and not as an explicit unit for acceleration. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

The first indicates an acceleration, the second is a velocity.

The acceleration value indicates that with each passing second the associated velocity increases by 3m/s.

While the second value idicates a velocity that does not change with respect to time.  As each second passes, the velocity remains at 3m/s.